# I cannot connect mysql database server with rails project? (Windows 7)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

I am very new in rails and using windows 7. In my windows machine i ve installed ruby 1.93, rails 3.2, Mysql 5.1 properly (also Install the MYSQL driver using this command "gem install mysql2"). I also put "libmySQL.dll" file into ruby/bin directory. I can create rails project and can run webrick server successfully..database server also get connected(using sqlite). But when i use mysql using "rails new app_name -d mysql" this command....mysql server is not get connected with rails project.
In my database.yml I have:

```
development:
adapter: mysql2
encoding: utf8
reconnect: false
database: untitled5_development
pool: 5
username: root
password:
host: localhost
```

Sorry for my bad english.
Thanks everyone

Comment: yes, it is running @AdamT

Comment: how do you know it doesn't connect? error?

Comment: the error is "Mysql2::Error (Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)):"

Comment: here is the error's screenshot https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4533313/error.JPG

Comment: Try removing the empty password key.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you have to set the password for the root user. Also note that older versions of ruby on rails would expect you to comment the database name. If you have not yet created the db.